# Testing: check that all resources are loaded

Tags: php, bdd, http-status-codes, behat

In the context of `BDD` and `php`, I've been looking for a way to check that all resources on a page are loaded.

I thought about using the status code but it looks like the only status code I can check using `mink` is the status code of the page itself like this:

`$session->getStatusCode()`

I'm looking for a way to make sure that the requests made to get the resources on the page (javascript, css, images etc.) also return status codes of 200.

Any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Only JavaScript can help you, try to send an AJAX request when the "onload" event is triggered.

Comment: this should be a comment!!

Comment: @AADTechnical

You can only comment on your own questions and answers when you have 1 rep

Comment: @KyleFairns yes, agree! But that post is way to vague. it seems like a assumed guess than an actual answer!